# Is there an OS X app for reducing an image to a specific file size

Tags: osx, images, image-processing

I'm currently dealing with a few applications that impose a 2mb limit on import file/image size. Currently, the only way I have found to deal with this is to manually find all images that are above 2mb, open them in preview, resize them to a certain percentage, and hope that the file size drops below 2mb (and if not, keep reducing).

This seems extraordinarily complicated. **Is there an OS X application that will take an image file and reduce it to a desired file size?**

Comment: What image formats do you need it to work on?

Comment: And does it have to be an OS X specific app with graphical interface, or would a cross-platform command line tool be fine as well?

Comment: @NickWilde 99% of the image formats are either .jpg or .png.

Comment: @Izzy a graphical interface is not necessary

Comment: OK, in this case I guess I have the perfect tool for you – see my answer :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm using **[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)** for this kind of task, usually approaching it via compression/quality or resolution. Example:

```
mogrify -resize 800x600 -quality 70
```

But according to the [list of command line options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php), an approach better matching your requirements is using the `jpeg:extent=value` parameter (e.g. `-define jpeg:extent=2048KB`). This will work via compression/quality alone, not reducing the resolution (if I understood the documentation correctly; I've never played with *this* option. You are free to combine it with `-resize`, though).

> Restrict the maximum JPEG file size, for example `-define jpeg:extent=400KB`. The JPEG encoder will search for the highest compression quality level that results in an output file that does not exceed the value. The `-quality` option is ignored if it is also present.

*ImageMagick* is cross-platform, and provides [Binary Releases](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) for Linux, Mac OS X, iOS, and Windows alike. It supports a ton of graphic formats (including your requested `.jpg` and `.png`). So this should fit your requirements. Due to its working from the command line, it's also faster than many other approaches (as it doesn't have to load a GUI first).

This is a pretty mighty package for image manipulation, so you can use it for many other related tasks as well: montage, animate, compare, identify (i.e. show image meta data), convert between different formats, … Might take a little time to grasp it *all,* though :)

Comment: +1 When I read the question yesterday I was thinking of finding the right -resize parameters by dichotomy through some wrapper script, -define might be more clever :) Ironically I knew some tools to set a target size for a video (many years ago when I was burning CD/DVD), but not for an image.

Comment: Thanks, @FranckDernoncourt! I was coming the same way, but did a Ctrl-F for "file size" on the manual before posting. Didn't know about this parameter until an hour ago :)