# Concatenate several images into a single image on Android

Tags: android, images

I am looking for an Android program with a GUI that can concatenate horizontally several images into a single image, just like we can do on computer with [ImageMagick](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7272/903) using `montage *.png -tile x1 -mode Concatenate out.jpg`. I saw some [ports of ImageMagick](https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick) on Android but they seem CLI at best I don't know how reliable they are.

Comment: If anyone has any idea

Comment: please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.