# Photo Editor: Stitching multiple images together

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, image-editor

Does anyone know of an easy to use (and free) photo editor that will allow me to stitch three images together? Anything that works on **Ubuntu 14.04** or **Windows 8/8.1** is fine.

The three images I am trying to connect are of a decently big spreadsheet I took screen shots of (20 rows and 8 columns, with 4 lines of text per cell). I am placing these images in a *README.md* file on *Github*.

What I've tried:

- Github allows me to place all three images in successive lines, which makes it sort of appear like it is one image, except that my cropping for the three images is a bit misaligned.
- I took one screenshot of the entire table by zooming way out in order to capture it all. The resulting crop had readable, but still too small, text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best image stitcher that I know of is [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) - it allows you to stitch images together that are not in a simple left/right or right/left order.

hugin is free, open source and cross platform including linux & windows.

On Ubuntu just use:

```
sudo apt-get install hugin
```

if it isn't already installed.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: If Steve wouldn't have already recommended it, I'd done so now. Using *Hugin* for years already on Linux. Didn't yet find anything coming even close to it. It even allows for lens correctures, correctures in dimensions (angles), blend modes, projections...

Comment: @Izzy - I think that it is a brilliant toolkit - forgot to mention perspective corrections, exposure and focus stacking, and lots of other goodies in their.

Comment: @SteveBarnes if you mention all features, nobody finds the other answers anymore :) It can even be [used for HDR](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/HDR_workflow_with_hugin.html)…

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) (open source and cross-platform) and use the command (assuming that your images are PNGs, which is [often the best choice for screenshots](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161779/20338)):

```
montage *.png -tile 1x -mode Concatenate out.jpg
```

- `-tile 1x`: concatenate vertically (use `-tile x1` for horizontal)
- `-mode Concatenate`: concatenate without any white space between the images

More details on the [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) program (part of ImageMagick) if interested.

---

Some ImageMagick useful commands for pre-processing your photos before the collage:

- you can [resize the image](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6877/903) (to approximately 2MB in this example) using:

  `mogrify -define jpeg:extent=2048KB out.jpg`
- you can modify the dimension of a bunch of images using (to 30% in this example):

  `mogrify -resize 30x30% *.png`

Also note that [JPEG/JFIF supports a maximum image size of 65535×65535 pixels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), while the PNG specification doesn't appear to place any limits on the width and height of an image; these are 4 byte unsigned integers, [which could be up to 4294967295](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4109447/395857) .

[image]

and if you are curious: [Why does ImageMagick's montage limit the JPG output to 65500 instead of 65535?](https://superuser.com/q/773356/116475)

---

FYI:

- [Comparison of photo stitching software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_stitching_software)