# Tool to turn video into long PNG

Tags: video, image-processing, png

I have some small video files that are a few seconds long, and I would like to turn them into long PNG files.  I'm not sure if there is a better way to say this.

For example, if one of the videos is 100px by 100px and 3 seconds long at 12 frames per second, the resulting PNG would be 100px by 3600px (or vise versa).

My current plan is to write a script that does this.  However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: After your first sentence, I had no idea what you were talking about.  Then your example made it perfectly clear! :-)  Interesting idea.

Comment: What OS must it run on? Any price limit? From your descruption, that somehow sounds like the film-strip I vaguely remember from Adobe Premiere (you could export frames that way to edit them e.g. with Photoshop and then re-import them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

1. [Convert video to images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6783/903)
2. [Concatenate images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/14735/903)